# Baxter and Robotics System Toolbox

Tags: matlab, robotics-system-toolbox

I am trying to setup a two way communication with the Baxter Robot using the Robotics System Toolbox from MATLAB. However, I am unable to move the arms or record a trajectory using the rosactionclient command. Is there a method to solve this problem?

The examples in the documentation provided by MATLAB uses rosactionclient for the PR2 arm, but is it the same for Baxter as well ?

Comment: I think that many thinks are hidden under the carpet here. Please provide at least,  OS, matlab version, toolbox version, ROS version.

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer is yes. [baxter API](http://sdk.rethinkrobotics.com/wiki/API_Reference)  do a search in the page for "Joint Trajectory Action".

You need to have all baxter related software installed.
Also from the first version of the toolbox the use of rosjava was not well documented and especially the use of custom msg/service/ was cumbersome. I hope that they fixed it by now but didn't have the time to look back.